# locating joomla files when I do inspet element in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, joomla

I am new to Joomla and I am trying to learn things as I go forward. In Firefox when I do inspect element on my site, I can find the CSS tag that I need to change in order to get the result I want, but I cant locate the file that I have to make the change in.

For instance right now my menu is shifted to the left and I did inspect element and I found

```
   #topmenu_holder {
    float: left;
}
```

if I change that float to right, then my issue is fixed. 
I Just don't know how to find that file to make that change.

Comment: I was able to find it. :), but if there is a way to locate the file easier, I would like to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css you're referring to is typically found in the Template that you are using, but which specific file depends on the template you're using - they're all located within the `\templates\` folder of your Joomla site.

Additionally, if you look around in the Firefox Inspection area, you'll probably see reference to the file it's contained in as shown in the attached image.

[image: Firefox Element Inspection]

Answer (score 0):

Have you found the place where you can edit your file in joomla - extensions - template manager - then edit template from there.  Dont look at the style option but the other one (template) you can edit all files there including css files.

There should be an option the overide the file. You should look to do this as joomla can overwrite existing file when updating. For now though this should get you started.